# Why does Visual Studio stop debugging my app?

Tags: visual-studio-2010, visual-studio-debugging

There's a really weird bug in my app (C#, WPF based UI): in a certain scenario, if I unpin the explorer, I'm getting tons of exceptions (System.NullReferenceException – Object reference not set to an instance of an object).

The problem is:  I can't find the specific reason for this exception because Visual Studio **stops debugging** (so there is no stacktrace, and no evidence for the exception).
I tried changing the exception handling settings in VS to throw any exception instead of handling it, but it didn't help.

How can I find the exact location which threw the exception?

Comment: Can you give more steps to help in reproducing this? any code?

Comment: I'm guessing this bug is specific to my app (and it's a huge app), so there is no way you could reproduce it..
My question is general.

Comment: Did you check the EventViewer ..you will get more information about your error there..

Comment: What exactly is "in a certain scenario", and what exactly are you doing when you "unpin the explorer"? If there's no way we could reproduce it, this question is too localized to be of use to future readers here.

Comment: The entities in my explorer appear in a tree like manner.
Sometimes (I don't know when and why), when I expand 2 or more nodes of the tree at the same time, and then unpin the explorer, I'm getting the exception.

Comment: does your app run correctly without debugging? may be you are trying to debug older version of code? that can cause a mismatch..also check if any configs are missing and dependencies too.

Comment: @KayzerSoze you say `there is no stacktrace, and no evidence for the exception` however you also said `I'm getting tons of exceptions (System.NullReferenceException` - how is this possible? if you know its a NullReferenceException how is it you cannot get the stack from this Exception?

Comment: I get a lot of popups which close immediately after they show.